# JQgrid - escape ':' in searchoptions (value part)

Tags: jqgrid

How to set the values for filter is explained here [link text](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config). I have two requirements.
1. the default value needs to be empty. I expect, if defaultValue is not set, the filter is empty, but that is not happening in my case.
2. How to escape ':' in my value. The character ':' and ';' are used to seperate the index and values. But, in my value string it contains a ':' (eg: searchoptions:{value:"1:'Level: 1'"} , where Level: 1 is my first value). How to escape : in the value part. I tried \ , / etc.

thanks.

Edit: Item 1 may be solved if there is no other way. I may set an additional item ALL in the values, and use it default.

Comment: I want only ask you whether my answer solve your problem or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, it seems impossible to use any escape character to place ':' inside of `value` of `searchoptions` if you define it like a string:

```
searchoptions:{value:"1:'Level: 1'"}
```

There is another form of setting of `value` of `searchoptions` - object form, which is also described under http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config#colmodel_options. For example you can use following syntax

```
searchoptions:{value:{'1:': 'Level: 1;', ':2:;': 'Level: 2;'}}
```

It defines a select with the texts "Level: 1;" and "Level: 2;" displayed and the corresponding values "1:" and ":2:;". It works.

Comment: though I never tested the above solution, as I took another approach already, I may treat it as answered my qn.. thanks for ur help and time.

Comment: FWIW, the official jqGrid blog states that it now has a workaround, considering only the first ':' as a separator of key:value options (within all the text contained between the ';' which separates options. This means now you can have any number of colons inside the string, and only the first will count as separator. More info here http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/problem-using-colon-in-editoptions-as-value . Additionaly, although useng an object instead of a string is valid, it has the disadvantage of losing the originial order of the list (it always orders it based on the index)

Comment: @DiegoDD: The answer is 6 years old. `searchoptions` supports now two properties: `separator`, with default value `":"` and `delimiter`, with default value `";"`. If one knows that the values can contains `:` then one can just specify `separator` with alternative symbol, which is not inside of the main values.

Comment: @Oleg : I am getting the same issue. My object will be like this `{"1200":"10:00-12:00","900":"07:00-09:00"}`. If I include `:all` option in the dropdown its not coming at the first option.. `{"":"All","1200":"10:00-12:00","900":"07:00-09:00"}`. I need that `All` option should come first.  Could be please help me?

Comment: @Ranjith: I recommend you to use **string** as the `value` of `searchoptions`. You can use `separator` and `delimiter` properties if `:` or `;` could be inside of the text or values. Additionally `noFilterText` is preferred for specifying `"":"All"` entry because the value will be used only in the filter toolbar, but not in the searching dialog. For example, `searchoptions: { noFilterText: "All", separator: "@", value: "1200@10:00-12:00;900@07:00-09:00" }`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the only option was to use searchoptions object.
However, I had to programmatically build the list so I couldn't use define the objects.

Therefore, I decided to use build the list as an JSON string and then parse it, as shown below:

```js
  searchoptions: {
    value: $.parseJSON("{" + searchSelectFormat.join(",") + "}"),
    sopt: ['eq']
  }
```

where searchSelectFormat is in the format of

```js
'"' + data + '":"' + data + '"';
```

'"' + item+ '":"' + item+ '"'