# Why can't jQuery jqGrid default my combobox correctly when I have a comma in the select values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqmodal

I am using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) with ASP.NET MVC.  I have an edit form which works great, but for some reason I have one combobox field that doesn't default to the current selected row after the first time I bring up the edit form.

I have found the root cause. The values in the dropdown all have commas in them as they are showing name in the format:

```
[LastName, FirstName]
```

When I remove the comma from the select values, the problem goes away.

Is there any way to support commas in a select dropdown on a jqGrid edit form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you will find the answer on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981409/jqgrid-escape-in-searchoptions-value-part/3023128#3023128): you should use object instead of string as the value of the `value` option for the list of select values.

Comment: can you clarify your answer a bit.  I don't fully understand what i need to do based on the question in the link

Comment: @ooo: You can use `value` parameter for the dropdown box in two forms: 1) string form: `value:"1:one;2:two"` 2) object form `value:{"1":"one","2":two"}`. If you use the string form, the values in every dropdown element have many restriction. If you use the second form you are much more free in the characters which you use. This is what I mean. If you modify your question with exact values (full definition of the corresponding column) which you use I could probably help you more.